# Transaction vs locking in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking

I have some confusing regarding transaction and locking in MySQL.

- What is difference between transaction and locking in MySQL and how it related to each other?
- Is transaction related to DML (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) only or it also related to SELECT query?
- Is transaction cover the Truncate?

for example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * from XYX; 
UPDATE abc SET summary=788 WHERE type=1; 
TRUNCATE TABLE pqr;
INSERT INTO ABL VALUE('OK');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

**What is [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)?**

> A transaction comprises a unit of work performed within a database
>   management system (or similar system) against a database, and treated
>   in a coherent and reliable way independent of other transactions.

Also, there is a [documentation on MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)

**What is [database lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28database%29)?**

> A lock, as a read lock or write lock, is used when multiple users need
>   to access a database concurrently.

So, it's completely different things, you can't 'compare' them.

Answer (score 0):

It's requires a large explanation to full cover your question.
In short a transaction is an "atomic operation". If it's committed all inside it is committed, if it's rolled back all inside it is rolled back.

Locks are a mechanism to avoid dirty and ghost reads (and two process to make updates at the same time, messing with one another) in parallel/concurrent environments.
In a general saying transaction levels defines locks strategies.

Almost everything is contained in a transaction, including the select and truncate.

I suggest you to hit the books to learn about transaction levels, locks (strategies, granularity, performance, deadlocks, starvation, glutton philosophers...)